# How to get a thing from a Json text?

Tags: php, json

i want to know how can i extract a word from a json encoded or decoded.
Example:
From:

```
{"51973658":{"id":51973658,"name":"Covrigel","profileIconId":748,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1419865098000}}
```

I want to see just "Covrigel".
Is that possible?

Comment: Most languages have JSON parsers.  Someone can specify the exact syntax and the name of a library if needed, but we'll need to know what language you are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple array. You can access that by something like this,

```
echo $array_name['51973658']['name'];
```

**EDIT after question change:**

```
$json = json_decode($json_array, true);
echo $json['51973658']['name'];
```

Comment: It's a JSON decoded, thats the coded one: {"51973658":{"id":51973658,"name":"Covrigel","profileIconId":748,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1419865098000}}

Comment: store that decoded result in variable and use above method.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is convert it to a PHP array.

```
$json = '{"51973658":{"id":51973658,"name":"Covrigel","profileIconId":748,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1419865098000}}';

$json = json_decode($json, $array = true);

echo $json['51973658']['name'];
```

Comment: I've edited this, i haven't any array variable, that's just a decoded JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Decode the JSON as an associative array then echo the value you need.

```
<?php

    $json = '{"51973658":{"id":51973658,"name":"Covrigel","profileIconId":748,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1419865098000}}';

    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    echo $data['51973658']['name'];    

?>
```